# Why isnt Bokeh generating extra y ranges here?

Tags: python, plot, charts, bokeh, multiple-axes

My Bokeh version is 0.12.13 and Python 3.6.0
I modified the example code available here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html

I have just tried to add one extra y range.

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
y2 = [10,9,8,7,6]
y3 = [23,24,25,26,27]

output_file("twin_axis.html")

p = figure(x_range=(0,6), y_range=(0,6))

p.circle(x, y, color="red")

p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo1": Range1d(start=0, end=11)}
p.circle(x, y2, color="blue", y_range_name="foo1")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo1"), 'left')

p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo2": Range1d(start=21, end=31)}
p.circle(x, y3, color="green", y_range_name="foo2")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo2"), 'right')

p.toolbar_location ="above"
show(p)
```

While the original code works well, my modified code doesnt. I am not able to figure out what mistake I am doing.I am a bit new to bokeh so please guide me in the right direction.
EDIT: There is no output when I add the third y axis. But it works with only 2 axes on the left side.

Comment: Not sure why anyone voted to close, this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are ***not*** adding another y-range — by reassigning a new dictionary to `p.extra_y_ranges`, you are ***replacing*** the old one, entirely. This causes problems when the axis you add expects the `"foo1"` range to exist, but you've blown it away. The following code works as expected:

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
y2 = [10,9,8,7,6]
y3 = [23,24,25,26,27]

output_file("twin_axis.html")

p = figure(x_range=(0,6), y_range=(0,6))

p.circle(x, y, color="red")

p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo1": Range1d(start=0, end=11)}
p.circle(x, y2, color="blue", y_range_name="foo1")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo1"), 'left')

# CHANGES HERE: add to dict, don't replace entire dict
p.extra_y_ranges["foo2"] = Range1d(start=21, end=31)

p.circle(x, y3, color="green", y_range_name="foo2")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo2"), 'right')

p.toolbar_location ="above"
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! Now I understood the basics. Thank you. And Thank you for developing Bokeh. I am loving it.

Comment: If you can upvote and/or mark correct that would also be appreciated :D

Comment: No upvote because of my lack of "reputation", but marked it correct. Thnx.

Comment: why are there two axis on the left now? how could you remove one of them?

Comment: There are two axes because an extra axis was explicitly added in the code above. That was the primary point of the question: "How do I add an extra axis"

Comment: Is it possible to add a twin axis without specifying the range?

Comment: No, it is not possible.